# php check text input length and change another input based on length

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have an php form utilizing several inputs that is driving a kiosk page.  If a text input is blank I want this update a separate input with the word "hidden"  If there is text I would like the word "visible" to show.  Currently my code works if you click submit twice but will not work on the first submit.  Here is my current code:

The if function that is current working on second submit:

```
if (strlen($something)>0) {
    $_POST['someone'] = "visible";
} else {
    $_POST['someone'] = "hidden";
}
```

input form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>something : </td>
<td><input type="text" id="something" name="something" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($something); ?>"/></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>someone:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="someone" name="someone" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($someone); ?>"/></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit"/></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table> 
</form>
```

Here is the update code:

```
$usql = "UPDATE test SET something= '".$_POST['something']."', someone= '". $someone ."' WHERE ID='a';";
```

Currently the "someone" input has a display of none so it cannot be seen by the user.  This is not necessary but if someone could tell me how to bypass adding an input altogether and tweak the update statement itself to update something that would be great as well!  Thanks!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use a ternary operator

Comment: Plus, your question is unclear as to whether or not you're using your entire code on the same page or in seperate files. If it worked on the second try, then this tells me you may be getting undefined index/variables notices. Error reporting will tell you if that's the case. That `$something` of your is also unclear as to where it's defined and where it's used.

Comment: Use session variables?

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is all on one page. The submit button redirects the user to the same page after update. Essentially refreshing the page so they can see the updates.

Comment: I've no way to tell which MySQL API you're using and how. If it's an error somewhere, check for them using the error handling that matches your MySQL API and PHP. You can also use a header to redirect to the same page on successful query, use a ternary operator and sessions. Those are my best guesses. If fetched from DB in a loop, that... I don't know.

Comment: @matt session variables is exactly what I needed. Thanks Matt. Can you put this in an answer so I can mark it complete.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my apologies for the lack of information. I am new to coding and my limited knowledge usually makes me provide too much or too little information. I'll get it down eventually. Thanks for your patience and time in helping me reach a solution to this question.

Comment: you're welcome Craig. Glad to see you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using session variables can save the page state, even after reload.

First page save:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['someone'] = $_POST['someone'];
```

Then:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['someone']))
{
    if (strlen($_SESSION['someone'])>0) {
        $_POST['someone'] = "visible";
    } else {
        $_POST['someone'] = "hidden";
    }
}
```